# Redelivering Activemq messages after consumer throws exception

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have a spring application with a consumer to consume messages and write them to a database. I'm using the spring DefaultMessageListenerContainer. Is there a way to consume a message and upon a database exception being thrown put the message back onto the queue?

Answer (score 1):

`setSessionTransacted(true)`

If you are using the namespace to configure the container, use

```
<jms:listener-container acknowledge="transacted" ...>
    <jms:listener ... />
</jms:listener-container>
```

You also might want to synchronize the database and JMS transactions by adding the JDBC transaction manager to the container configuration.

See [Dave Syer's Javaworld Article about Distributed transactions in Spring, with and without XA](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html)